# Install builder for Java application

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am looking for a framework to create an install kit for my Java web application. 
I need something that would install JBoss, a Database Server, Java, and of course the application itself with all the dependencies and settings on a Windows platform.

I prefer free tools. What do you recommend and why?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out earlier in a comment there is another similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application), which anwsers my question. Thanks to @Zaki for this info.

Answer (score 1):

Install4J: Not free but easy to use and extensible.

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [SetupBuilder Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder) to create a native msi installer with a simple Gradle script.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11817153)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf What you are missing in the answer? Its contain the name and the download link. Its sounds that you have not work before with such tools/frameworks. If you does not understand the topic then you should not review it.