# packaging java application

Tags: java, jar

I have a java application from which I build a jar that relies on many third party jars, what's the best/common way of packaging this application for end user distribution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application

Comment: What operating systems are you targeting? Do you need to stick with a "pure java" solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use a build tool like [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/) or something similar, and use that to manage your dependencies and build a all-in-one package.

Otherwise, you'd mostly be stuck with messing with manifest files. Although, IDEs like Eclipse or NetBeans may help you a bit with that.

Comment: other option to maven is ant, still I prefer Maven

Answer (score 3):

The way packaging is done. There are two ways

1. **wrap as executable:** This is common, if you know the supportable platform and wrap the Jar in executable. And distribute it. Something like this http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ (I have not used this, but there are similar wrapper available)
2. **Bundle all Jar and provide script:** You can use [Maven's Assembly plug-in to bundle everything in one Jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). With this done, you can distribute with a `bat` file and a `.sh` file for Windows and Linux based systems respectively. If you see Glassfish is distributed in similar manner. These scripts has executable command and, often take parameters for different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Fat Jar Eclipse Plug-In](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

**OR**

[Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications in NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html)