# How to unpack a binary file in java?

Tags: java, binary, unpack

May somebody help me to know how can I do in java what I do in ruby with the code below.

The ruby code below uses **unpack('H*')[0]** to stores the complete binary file content in variable "var" in ASCII format.

```
IO.foreach(ARGV[0]){ |l| 

        var = l.unpack('H*')[0]

} if File.exists?(ARGV[0])
```

**Update:**
Hi Aru. I've tested the way you say in the form below

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(testFile.toPath());
str = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(str);
```

But when I print the content of variable "str", the printout shows only little squares, like is not decoding the content. I'd like to store in "str" the content of binary file in ASCII format.

**Update #2:**
Hello Aru, I'm trying to store in array of bytes all the binary file's content but I don't know how to do it. It worked
with "FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(myFile);" but this is an external library, is there a built in option to do it?

```
File myFile = new File("./Binaryfile");
byte[] binary = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(myFile); //I have issues here to store in array of bytes all binary content
String hexString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(binary);
System.out.println(hexString);
```

**Update #3:**

Hello ursa and Aru, Thanks for your help. I've tried both of your solutions and works so fine,  but seeing Files.readAllBytes() documentation
it says that is not intended to handle big files and the binary file I want to analyse is more than 2GB :(. I see an option with your solutions, read
chunk by chunk. The chunks inside the binary are separated by the sequence FF65, so is there a way to tweak your codes to only process one chunk at a 
time based on the chunk separator? If not, maybe with some external library.

**Update #4:**
Hello, I'm trying to modify your code since I'd like to read variable size chunks based of 
value of "Var".

How can I set an offset to read the next chunk in your code?

I mean, 
- in first iteration read the first 1024, 
- In this step Var=500
- in 2d iteration read the next 1024 bytes, beginning from 1024 - Var = 1024-500 = 524
- In this step Var=712
- in 3rd iteration read the next 1024 bytes, beginning from 1548 - Var = 1548-712 = 836
- and so on

is there a method something like read(number of bytes, offset)?

Comment: [`Files.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) reads all bytes from a file. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Aru. Thanks for your answer, but is not working. Please se my update in original question. Thanks

Comment: I did add another example to my post on how to only read a certain amount of bytes from the file.

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use commons-codec [Hex class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) + commons-io [FileUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
byte[] binary = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("/Users/user/file.bin");
String hexEncoded = Hex.encodeHex(binary);
```

But if you just want to read content of TEXT file you can use:

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Users/user/file.txt", "ISO-8859-1");
```

With JRE 7 you can use standard classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    char[] hexChars = new char[data.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < data.length; j++ ) {
        int v = data[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    System.out.println(new String(hexChars));
}
```

Comment: Hello ursa, thank you. It seems it work, I needed to download common-packs.jar and I located in my project folder using netbeans. Runs fine in netbeans console, but when I build the project doesn't work. Where should be located the commons-pack.jar? Somewhere inside Programfiles/java/...?

Comment: it is very wide question for separate discussion. you can start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4650054/2078908

Comment: @Zurix If you add the library correctly to your project in Netbeans, it should put all libraries in a subfolder /lib when building and add them to the classpath. But there is no need to use an external library, Java already has this functionality built in: [`DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary-byte:A-)

Comment: Hi ursa/Aru, Thanks for all your help. May you see my update #2 in original post please. I'm trying to follow your
suggestion to use the built in DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(binary), but I have issues.

Comment: Hi ursa/Aru, both of your solutions work, but I found another issue. May you please see my update 3 in original post. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
try {
    File inputFile = new File("someFile");
    byte inputBytes[] = Files.readAllBytes(inputFile.toPath());
    String hexCode = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(inputBytes);
    System.out.println(hexCode);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't read file: " + e);
}
```

If you don't want to read the entire file at once, you can do  so as well. You'll need an `InputStream` of some sort.

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    byte inputBytes[] = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes;
    // Read until all bytes were read
    while ((readBytes = input.read(inputBytes)) != -1) {
        System.out.printf("%4d bytes were read.\n", readBytes);
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(inputBytes));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't read file: " + ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error while reading file: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: Hello Aru, it works so fine. I'm trying to modify your code to read sequentially each chunk. But the chunks have variable size. May you see my update in original post please. Thanks so much for your help. Is the last step to get working.