# how to convert java web application into single windows installer?

Tags: web-applications, windows-installer, binaryformatter

I have developed a  java web application using eclipse, struts 2 framework and JSP.It is a ERP software application where i want to distribute it to the end user in a form of binary format where user can install the application using installers.(please suggest the which one will be suitable)for window platform.
My other requirement is I want bundle all software’s with java web application as a single windows intaller.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a setup authoring tool which creates an MSI or EXE package for your application. Here is a discussion about Java installer tools: [What are good InstallAnywhere replacements for installing a Java EE application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application)

This way your clients will receive a single setup file which handles your application install process.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a deployer not installer exactly you need to pack up the web app(.war, just an example for java )  and container and you can distribute with some configurations file based structure

Comment: If I packed up .war file means, i am in need of tomcat server to run application.I am in need to pack up all the softwares into single windows installer.Please give suggestion(bundle all the softwares into single exe file). Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be a zip file you can just extract and use it

Comment: Thanks for your response.The enduser cannot know what are the softwares we used.(all the softwares installed as background process just click single exe file.)

Comment: you could put your precious :)  s/w  on server and give user the clients

Comment: Is there any possibilities to set single exe file in server itself