# Deploy web app java project that self installs tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, sql-server-ce, exe

how to deploy a *web app java project* which depends on **tomcat** and **Sql Server Compact Edition** (`SqlCE`) ?
so that the final user can only install the `.jar` (I don't know if it can be an `.exe` or not) and the setup takes care of installing `tomcat` (portable edition?) and `SqlCE`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two options:

1. Use components written in java (for instance: embedded jetty as a web server, HSQLDB as a database). Then you can ship your whole application as a JAR archive (or few JARS) and create batch script which will run it (.bat under Windows, .sh under Linux or even .exe installator of some sort). This, however, might require some additional work.
2. Use some sort of EXE instalator wizard which will: 1. Install Tomcat into specified directory, 2. Install your desired DB, 3. Copy your webapp WAR inside newly created Tomcat installation

I would go for 1, since it will work on every OS.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, the project must be run under Apache Tomcat , and SQL Server; i wish i had the choice to choose but i don't, so i guess i'll think about the second option, do u know any specific EXE instalator wizard ?

Comment: It appears that you can run Tomcat as embedded container. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6
When it comes down to an installer, I don't have that much experience programming under Windows, sorry. I guess Google would be the best choice.

Comment: Try [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) or (Install Builder)[http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/] or read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application