# Is there a way to remotely install to program to a windows machine from both a windows or a linux machine? Preferably something easy to code in java

Tags: java, windows, linux, installation, windows-installer

I have a java application that will run on either a windows or linux machine and needs to be able to remotely install an application to a windows machine. I'd love a single way to do this in java that is coded the same for windows/linux machine as the installer, but that might be impossible, so I'm open to other suggestions.

If its impossible for there to be one way, could you recommend ways for linux ->windows and windows -> windows install that are simple?

Answer (score 1):

Two commercial solutions come to mind that support "unattended" installation which ought to permit remote installation:

- [Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html)
- [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/)

There is a more comprehensive list of cross-platform Java installers in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application).