# Can we access a VMX appliance by a name?

Tags: vmware-player

I want to distribute a [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) 2 application as a VMX appliance running Jeos. I had seen an [Openbravo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbravo) demo which was distributed as a VMX appliance. However, the appliance had to be accessed by typing an IP address in the browser. Is there a way to configure the appliance such that end user can access the appliance by typing a name, like a domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what I wanted to achieve can be done using ways other than a VM appliance. I found some interesting information [about deploying web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759855/what-are-good-installanywhere-replacements-for-installing-a-java-ee-application)