# what are the Ways to create a gui to install a java app

Tags: java, installation-package

I have a java web application .
Currently the application is installed in a cli mode [on windows/linux /solaris] by running sh or cmd scripts.
I would like to create a GUI for the App installation so that user can edit info in gui for the installation.

Any pointers/Best practices for developing  gui would be helpful.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this covers it.

[How to create Java webapp installer (.exe) that includes Tomcat and MySQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856772/create-installer)

Answer (score 1):

IzPack (http://izpack.org/) is one that seems stable and actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Swing.  This is the GUI framework that comes with Java.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/

```
public class Swing extends JFrame{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    new Swing();
  }
  public Swing(){
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world!");
    add(label);
    setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```