# Making Installer for Java application with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, deployment, installation, java

I am looking for an installer for my Java Application that can bundle my own JRE and MySQL database, and I have heard of Install4J.  Does Install4J have the feature of bundling MySQL Database 5.0 so that my customers can easily install the application with MySQL as the database?

Comment: Please Help as i am stuck

Comment: Similair Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856772/create-installer/856815

Comment: Have you considered Aapche Derby instead of mySQL? It is pure java and can be embedded as a jar in your application, so if there is no special need for MySQL it might be an option.

Comment: Should i convert my tables and procedures into Apache Derby

Comment: Hi  Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen do i need to convert my MySQL tables and Stored Procedures in Derby

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Advanced installer. download from http://www.advancedinstaller.com/.

You can bundle jre and database files

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Inno Setup**.Download from http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

for installing mysql and jre ,you can use batch files and calling in **inno setup**.

you should silent install mysql and jre with batch files.

example for silent install jre7u7:

```
jre-7u7.exe /s UPDATE=0
```

example for silent install mysql:

```
msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.21.msi" /quiet INSTALLDIR="%PROGRAMFILES%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5"
```

exmaple for silent configure instance mysql:

```
MySQLInstanceConfig.exe -i -q "-lC:\mysql_install_log.txt" "-nMySQL Server 5.5" "-p%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5" -v5.5.21 "-t%PROGRAMFILES%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my-template.ini" "-c%pro%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIXED ConnectionUsage=OLTP Port=3306 ServiceName=Mysql Charset=utf8
```

Comment: does Inno setup support running a script too prior to install. For e.g after creating DB, we can run .sql file to create tables?