# How to bundle JSP tomcat web application in a single installer

Tags: jsp, tomcat, installation

I have seen large application like joget workflow and alfresco which is actually a Webapps(Mysql, Tomcat, etc) which bundled and installed like desktop application.

I want to know how to create like those ? i mean how to bundle and create the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an installer like the traditional exe file under windows. What java uses for deploying applications are two types of files. WAR and EAR files.

1. **EAR** (Enterprise ARchive) is a file format used by Java EE for packaging one or more modules into a single archive so that the deployment of the various modules onto an application server happens simultaneously and coherently. It also contains XML files called deployment descriptors which describe how to deploy the modules. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29)) You can use Ant or Maven to build EAR files.
2. **WAR** file (or Web application ARchive) is a JAR file used to distribute a collection of JavaServer Pages, Java Servlets, Java classes, XML files, tag libraries, static Web pages (HTML and related files) and other resources that together constitute a Web application. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29))

These types of files can be easily [deployed](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) to Java EE compliant application containers easily usually using the servers administration console or even by using hot deployment.

Comment: can i also include mysql in the EAR file ? does the EAR file can be installed and uninstalled ?

Comment: no, you can use an EAR file to deploy JEE modules. You cannot include other software like exe files.

Comment: What you might be talking about is xamp (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) to do this kind of job

Comment: after search and search, i have found the solution in the stack overflow, this is what i meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856772/create-installer

Comment: The accepted answer does not answer the question at all. If I understand correctly, the questioner wants to know, how to package the application, including the application server and the database into an installer. XAMPP is an installer for apache, mysql, php. It has nothing to do with java or tomcat or any webcontainer.