# Deploy web application on JBoss via custom installer

Tags: java, jboss, installation, exe

I am not sure where should I start from as I have to deploy a web application on JBoss via custom installer.

I have created the *Dynamic Web Apllication* which comunicates with BES (*BlackBerry Enterprise Server*) to perform some operations on devices.

Now I want to create a installer file (*.exe*) file which will take care of following things:

1. Installation of JBoss server on client machine
2. Deploy my application on JBoss server

so that I just have to give that installer file to client and on single click the installer will do all the things for me.

Answer (score 2):

- Package the normal (unmodified) JBoss distribution into your installer
- The installer unpacks the JBoss distribution, and uses `jboss-cli.sh` to configure it.
- The installer copies your application into the deployment directory

---

- Configure and deploy your application on your development system (including data sources etc.)
- Package that JBoss installation into your installer (you probably don't need the content in `.../standalone/data/`)
- The installer just unpacks that JBoss installation on the client's system

---

The 2nd options possibly seems to be easier, but in the long run, the 1st option is superior, because you automatically get a script of all configuration changes.

Note: The 1st option requires JBoss 7

Comment: thanks for reply but how I can write installer or what is it ? I dont know anything about it

Comment: which will be the best installer tool for me ?

Comment: Just pick one installer (you can start from here: [Create installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856772/create-installer). Give it a try, and if you encounter an installer specific question, you can post another question. Otherwise your question (and the answers) would be too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried to create the exe file throw installer4j but I can not able to Install JBoss server and deploy the application on server pls see my friends post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027705/steps-to-deploy-web-application-on-jboss-via-install4j-installer

Comment: I tried to create the .exe file of my application using 2ed approach but I am facing some issue like 1] Automatically start JBoss Server 2] How to Set VM arguments or any link wold be helpfull

Comment: There must be some way to add a script in that installer. I can't really help with that, and we should have this discussion anyway in the other thread.