# Steps to deploy web application on JBoss via install4j installer

Tags: java, jboss, installation, exe, install4j

I am not sure where should I start from as I have to deploy a web application on JBoss via install4j installer.

I have created the Dynamic Web Apllication and I want to deploy this application on JBoss but deploy a war file and configure JBoss on client machine is not a good idea thus I want to create a installer file (.exe) file which will take care of following things:

1. Installation of JBoss server on client machine
2. Deploy my application on JBoss server

so that I just have to give that installer file to client and on single click the installer will do all the things for me and as I am new to install4j tool, I am not able to do this with install4j tool.Anyone can provide simple steps to create .exe file using install4j or any other tools

**EDIT**
what I tried so far

- General Settings

*1.1 Application Info*

Specify all The information like full name,Short name,version...

*1.2 Java version*

```
min version=1.4 
max version=1.7
```

***NOTE: Confuse about the Environment variables JAVA_HOME,JDK_HOME***

*1.3 Languages*

English-en

*1.4 Media File Options*

```
    Media File Output Directory:*/home/shekhar/*
    Media file Pattern 

name:${compiler:sys.shortName}_${compiler:sys.platform}_${compiler:sys.version}
```

Use LZMA compression
***Note:    Rest of options are unchanged***

- Files

  *2.1 Distribution Files*
  Add Files and Directories:specify the path where application exists 
  Note:   Rest of options are unchanged
- Launchers

  *3.1 Generated Launcher*
      add a new Launcher
- Installer

  Unchanged
- Media

  Installer
      create a new installer by default
- build

  *6.1 Start Build*

  Preparing configuration

  ```
  Creating media file 'Unix Installer':
    Collecting files:
    Compiling launchers:
      Compiling launcher 'connector':
        Generating launcher script file
        Generating VM options file connector.vmoptions.
    Creating media file: 
      Generating launcher script file
      Zipping custom code & resources JAR file
      Identifying components
      Shrinking runtime
      Compressing files
      Applying LZMA compression
    Moving media files to media directory /home/shekhar/Desktop
    The name of the media file is she_unix_1_0_0.sh (click to execute)
    The size of the media file is 1.7 MB

  Writing md5sums.
  Writing updates.xml.

  To check your settings, you can generate a project report

  Build was completed in 13.9 seconds.
  ```

I have run this exe but it has created application folder structure but where is JBoss Configuration and how can i  deploy this apllication on JBoss

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Otherwise it's very likely that this question gets closed.

Comment: I have wrote everything which i have done

Comment: install4j offers "Miscellaneous actions" which allow to "Execute an arbitrary executable" (to execute `jboss-cli.sh`). And there are "File operation actions" (to copy the .war into the deployment directory). Have you tried this?

Comment: @Beryllium thanks for reply. I have not tried this and I am not getting Miscellaneous actions and File operation actions and I have not got this options in install4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying a web application locally involves copying a WAR file to a specific directory which in the case of JBoss is the `standalone\deployments` directory. in install4j, you can use a "Copy file or directory" action to copy a war file from a distribution tree to an arbitrary directory.

Comment: thanks for reply but I am not getting "Copy file or directory" action tab in install4j

Comment: I have packaged Myapplication.war file in the JBOss Standalone/deployments/ folder and Install4j is creating exe file and exe file is extracting MyApplication but It is not starting JBoss automatocally.and where should i set vm parameters in install4j

Comment: The actions can be added on Installer->Screens & Actions, you should add them toe the "Installation" screen of the installer. What did you do in install4j so that JBoss should start automatically?

Comment: @Indo Kegel.Actually I am not getting anything.I have already told which i have done. so Please give me steps to deploy web application on JBoss via install4j installer from the beginning