# Converting web application into exe file

Tags: apache, servlets, jakarta-ee, exe

Dears, I already created a Java EE web application.

This app has Java Bean, servlets, JPA, Apache server and running the server by Glassfish. When starting the app, I have to run the server manually, then the DB.

How can i let the end user use it, or installer when he clicks on it so it runs on the server and starts the application directly?

Please, I can not find an answer for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an exe for your Java EE web Application is not possible.
The WAR file is the closest to it.

More info: [How to create Java webapp installer (.exe) that includes Tomcat and MySQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856772/how-to-create-java-webapp-installer-exe-that-includes-tomcat-and-mysql)

Comment: Thank u so much i'll read the article now :)