# How to make Java application standalone?

Tags: java, windows, deployment, software-distribution

I have to burn a Java application on a CD. This application have to run on every Windows PC wihtout any installation (also JRE shouldn't be installed) before.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is essentially same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable Both are about distributing a Java app as Windows .exe launcher (with JRE bundled in).

Comment: I'm not focused on getting a .exe-file. I'm only want to run the jre without the jdk.

I solved it with a batch-file and startet with the command jdk/java.exe bla.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way... [Bundle Java (the JRE) and Launch a Java App with 7zip SFX! ... (Convert Java Apps to an Executable, sort of)](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx.html)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you could copy the JRE from your programs folder onto the CD too. Then, add a batch script to use your "local" JRE to start your app. That should be enough, but I don't know if this works with all versions of windows.

Comment: The problem isn't Windows, that will happily run a Win32 PE executable from anywhere. But does the JRE make additional assumptions?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to bundle jre on disk and create startup scripts.
If you are not satisfied with simple batch / shell startup scripts you can use something like JLauncher to create "real" executable.

Comment: +1. If a commercial tool is ok, install4j is good for creating a .exe launcher (with bundled JRE) for Java apps. See e.g this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable/2258946#2258946

Comment: Ah, I should've recommended exe4j by the same company instead: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html Not much difference from technical point of view (when it comes to making launchers), but it costs much less than install4j.

Answer (score 4):

[JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) can do the trick with bundling JRE or prompting install Java, and it is **free**. You can also set properties for JVM

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to include an unpacked Java installation on the CD and use it to run the application.

There are AFAIK only 2 "Java to exe" compilers still on the market, one of which (Excelsior JET) is quite expensive, and the other (GCJ) doesn't work on Programs that use AWT or Swing.

Comment: Also (at least) install4j does "Java to exe". To my knowledge it's the best of Java installer/launcher tools.

Comment: @Jonik: The software Michael Borgwardt was referring to are compilers, that create native code out of Java-Sources. install4j creates an exe-launcher for starting the Java-Bytecode with the proper JVM. That should be sufficient in most cases, but isn't really the "Java to exe" that Michael had in mind.

Comment: @Mnementh, ah, thanks for clarification. Looking at the original question, I don't think OP would need real "Java-to-native-code" though.

Comment: @Jonik: What does it actually do? I couldn't tell from the worthless marketing BS on their homepage. An installer is not what's wanted here, nor a launcher that looks through the system for existing JREs.

Comment: Launcher **with bundled JRE**. (For example; this happens to be what OP needed.) See my comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712768/how-to-make-java-application-standalone/2712792#2712792. Their "features" page actually isn't marketing BS at all: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html (I've used this tool myself and know that it *is* good.)

Answer (score 1):

Just burn a jre onto the cd as well and start your application inside a batch script, which sets the CLASSPATH and the JAVA_HOME variables pointing to your jre.