# Updating a bundled JRE

Tags: java

I'm wanting to bundle my application with a JRE, much in the manner [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283388/stripping-the-jre-to-be-bundled-with-an-application-what-can-i-omit), or further explained in [this blog](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx.html).

Once you have bundled your JRE into your application is there a way to provide updates to that JRE?

Comment: Bundling a JRE & getting it to update seem to be mutually opposed strategies.  If you want an auto-updated JRE, launch the app. using JWS (and specify `n.n+` in the version string).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson JWS would be an option, except that the application will be deployed to intranets with very limited internet connectivity. The need for bundling the JRE is to insulate the application from other applications that are installed and make changes to the system JRE (upgrades are generally fine, but downgrades tend to be an issue...)

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious answer is: **You can provide JRE updates with your software updates**, i.e. new SFX. You can also write a script which will handle contents of archive, but is seems too messy for me.
Of course it depends of whether application extracts JRE each time you want to run it **OR** just once and then checks: if it had been extracted before then launch extracted app or extract and launch newly extracted app. In first case you can provide updates pretty easily.