# I make my executable jar in exe format,but i want to add jre with this

Tags: java, deployment, installation

I make my executable jar in exe format, but I want to add JRE with this because if JRE is not present in their machine, they can use it with this included JRE.

But I do not want to install this JRE in their machine.  This JRE is only used by this application only.  It will just like game or other application.  I use launch4j to make jar to exe but i did not find any option from where it can attach JRE and it has no option from where I can link my jar dynamically.

How do I achieve that?

If there is other free installer then mention it, and please give the procedure with example.

Comment: This SO question should cover it all:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable

Comment: @das_weezul *"This SO question should cover it all:"*  It covers everything bar pointing out that creating an EXE is a 2nd (or perhaps 3rd) class option.

Comment: @yes my application is in swing based GUI application and I want to use free installer.

Comment: @Andrew WebStart also expects a JRE to be installed. It just offers the user to download and install it. That restricts usage on locked down machines. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-137531.html

Comment: @das_weezul *"locked down machines."*  Utterly irrelevant.  An executable installer will fail on those machines as well.

Comment: @Andrew Jou could have written 1 decent answers in the same time you wrote all of your comments. At least that way others would benefit from it. But I'm sure a 10k SO member like you is aware of that.

Comment: @das_weezul I was too busy checking (and correcting) the dross coming from you, while at the same time, **clarifying the requirement.**

Answer (score 2):

Since it has been established that your app. has a GUI, I will suggest [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as **the** answer.

> But I do not want to install this JRE in their machine.

That is not a sensible requirement.  The user might already have a usable JRE installed, if they don't they probably also don't want every Java based application to be installing its own 'private' JRE.

Oracle's `deployJava.js` can do the checking, and help guide the user through the steps of installing (which basically comes down to click 'OK' when prompted).

> I make my executable jar in exe format,..

If you only intend to support Windows, what is the attraction of coding in Java?  JWS supports any platform for which Java is available.  That brings a lot more potential customers for the app.

> I want to use free installer.

JWS is entirely free.  Just like the JRE.

> ..please give the procedure with example.

Do you run an IDE?  If not, do you otherwise have Ant installed?  If that is a yes to either one, check out my small [JNLP API examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  Each comes with complete source and a build file (an Ant `build.xml`).

Within a couple of keystrokes & a few moments, you can see the app. installed and launched on your desktop.  For the end user, it is even simpler.  Just click a link in a web page, and it all happens automatically (possibly with a security prompt - for the protection of the user).

Answer (score 0):

I like JSmooth. You can give it a try here:
http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/features.php

> **Flexible automatic Java VM detection**
>
> - Detects the location of any Sun JVM installed. The wrappers use
>   several strategies to detect all the JVM available on a computer,
>   using windows registry, environment variables, windows path.
> - Detects
>   and uses Microsoft's JView (for 1.0 and 1.1 Java applications), if
>   available.
> - The JVM search sequence is fully customizable using the
>   GUI. You can force the executable to search in the path first, and in
>   the registry last, or in JAVA_HOME first. We have all the flavours!
> - Sometimes it's more convenient to **bundle a JRE with your application**.
>   JSmooth can deal with that too, you just need to define in which
>   folder the JRE is expected. It falls back nicely to a standard JVM
>   search if the JRE is not where it should be.
> - Specify which versions of
>   the JVM are compatible with your software. You can set a minimum
>   version, but also a maximum JVM version.

**Documentation:** http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html

Comment: if you give the procedure step by step it will be helpful for me,and one thing is that after making exe there must no dialog will  be opened like "trial version or jSmooth etc"

Comment: *"Detects and uses Microsoft's JView (for 1.0 and 1.1 Java applications), if available."*  Wait (checks watch) What millennium is this?

Comment: @saba There is a detailed manual/documentation (see link above) and jSmooth is GPL, so no Nag-Screens are to be expected

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at launch4j.
I had to use it, and it worked out very well.

You can set a minimum version of a needed JRE, bundle a JRE, or if a JRE is not found (and not bundled) the launcher may lead the user to a download location of an appropriate JRE.

There are various further features launch4j offers, and as opposed to another suggestion here, launch4j is activly developed

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/