# A standalone (Windows) JRE?

Tags: jar, exe, java

I would like to distribute a Java application for Windows.  It's Windows-only because it uses several Windows-specific features built into Java.  I'd like them to be able to use it regardless of whether they have the JRE installed.  So basically, that requires a standalone executable that requires no installation that you can simply run and pass a `jar` as an argument, or something similar.

Does something like this exist?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable) because I don't have the intention of making a single executable, nor are non-free solutions an option.  Most of the options were not free, and the rest didn't work. (For example, IKVM, the .NET JVM, failed to run the `jar` I'm using) But if it is, please close the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oracle JRE can be distributed.

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jrereadme-182762.html

"The Java(TM) Platform, Standard Edition Runtime Environment (JRE(TM)), excluding the JavaFX(TM) runtime, is intended for software developers and vendors to redistribute with their applications."

Look for the instructions for "private application runtime".