# How to deploy EJB application as an Exe file

Tags: deployment, ejb-3.0

I'm sorry if this question annoys you. I've written an EJB-based application and now I want to deploy it as a single Exe file (not a War file). That means if that Exe file's executed, all related things such as the web server, the database server, ... will be automatically installed to enable my application run smoothly. The JIRA installer's a typical example (http://www.atlassian.com/try).
I've googled a lot but I can't find the right answer. Would you please tell me how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish has a embedded Java ee container: http://embedded-glassfish.java.net That will allow you to embedd a Webserver and database into your app (infact a complete Java EE container).

The next step would be to embedd a a java-runtime and bundle it with above as an exe. I havnt tried that. But start with the above step and see if it is enough, then start by reading about this: [Embed a JRE in a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable)